# How to "bind -x" keyboard shortcut and refresh prompt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to bind git branch toggling to a keystroke via following configuration:

```bsh
bind -x '"\et":"git checkout -"'
```

This works like charm, however I also have following setup code for displaying branch name in PS1:

```bsh
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@:\W $(parse_git_branch)\$ '
```

The branch name is nor refreshed after calling my keyboard shortcut until I do, say, `cd .`.

The only known workaround I'm aware of is to update config as follows:

```bsh
bind '"\et":"git checkout - \n"'
```

Not a big deal, but I wonder what would be the best way to achieve desirable behavior with '-x' key preserved. What I've googled so far is there's [`redraw-current-line`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573269/bash-is-there-a-way-to-invoke-bind-commands-e-g-redraw-current-line-programm) function but the thing is it's not installed on my Ubuntu and I have no idea how to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redraw-current-line` is a command in readline, you don't install it. Bash uses the readline library and that's it, the command is already there. You use it with the `bind` builtin.

My tests indicate `redraw-current-line` redraws the prompt without re-evaluating it. `PROMPT_COMMAND` is not triggered, so you cannot use it to update the prompt either. For comparison: `clear-screen` behaves similarly.

In other words Bash remembers your prompt and redraws it without running `parse_git_branch` again. It seems the only way to actually re-evaluate is to type a command (possibly empty) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Your `"git checkout - \n"` emulates this: `git checkout -`  is the command and `\n` works like <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I understand in at least one aspect `bind -x '"\et":"git checkout -"'` is better than `bind '"\et":"git checkout - \n"'`. The former binding can be used while typing a random command and it doesn't interfere with what you typed. The latter binding generates a mess in such case.

But only the latter binding re-evaluates the prompt.

There is a relatively complex way to have your cake and eat it:

```bsh
_save_command_line() {
   READLINE_LINE_OLD="$READLINE_LINE"
   READLINE_POINT_OLD="$READLINE_POINT"
   READLINE_LINE=
   READLINE_POINT=0
}

_restore_command_line() {
   READLINE_LINE="$READLINE_LINE_OLD"
   READLINE_POINT="$READLINE_POINT_OLD"
}

bind -x '"\C-x\C-s":"_save_command_line; git checkout -"'
bind -x '"\C-x\C-r":"_restore_command_line"'
bind '"\et":"\C-x\C-s\n\C-x\C-r"'
```

Now if you type <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> then Bash will:

- send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to itself, this will run `_save_command_line; git checkout -`; note `_save_command_line` not only saves but also clears the command line;
- send `\n` to itself, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> which works like <kbd>Enter</kbd>; so it's <kbd>Enter</kbd> in our now empty command line; this will re-evaluate `PS1` and print a new prompt;
- send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to itself, this will run `_restore_command_line`.

This way you can run `git checkout -` *and* re-evaluate the prompt without disrupting the current command line.

Comment: How can I programmatically send `Esc t` to the current shell? I'm thinking of having a separate OS process send this hotkey to the current shell every second or so to force re-evaluation of the prompt string.

Comment: @LinusArver This is a separate question. [Ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) then. To provide context, in your question you can include a link to this answer. Try to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). You do not necessarily want to send keystrokes, you want to re-evaluate the prompt automatically. If you manage to send keystrokes then sooner or later they will interfere with `htop`, `mc`, `alsamixer` or something else you will run from the shell.

Comment: Posted https://superuser.com/questions/1756385/how-to-automatically-refresh-the-bash-prompt-every-second. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer can be simplified into this:

```
bind -x '"\C-x\C-s":"git checkout -"'

bind '"\et":"\C-x\C-s\n"'
```

- 1. Bind our command using -x.
- 2. Bind that we actually call. Without a trace, calling new line to update the prompt.