# How to automatically refresh the Bash prompt every second?

Tags: command-line, bash

As far as I can see, the user *must* press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to update `PS1`, `PROMPT_COMMAND`, etc. Is there some way to automatically update `PS1` and have it get displayed on the screen (without messing up any text already written by the user) without the user having to do anything?

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1662149/414551), it appears that you can press a hotkey to get automatic prompt re-evaluation without pressing `ENTER`. However the downside there is that the user must now manually press some new hotkey instead (we're back to square 1).

FWIW, in Zsh this is a solved problem [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17915260/437583).

Ultimately, I want to update things like the current time and battery level show itself on the prompt and update automatically without myself having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or some other key combination. I realize that `tmux` or `screen` can help here (solve the problem in these alternatives, not in Bash itself), but I am strictly interested in Bash solutions only.

Comment: I honestly think stuff like this is the reason why Zsh was created; a more modern shell for more modern tastes and needs.